# How to copy data from one s3 bucket to another using async io( fast manner) in python?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, boto3, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I want to do multiple copy objects from one s3 bucket to another in asynchronous manner and also I want to maintain there status.

I have already tried using async and await on s3 boto3 library but they doing sequential copy. I have also tried using aiobotocore and aioboto3 libraries but they don't have proper copy_object API as used in boto3.

```
async def copy_file(taskdescriptor: list, buckets: list):
    #loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    print("taskdescriptor", taskdescriptor)
    for job in taskdescriptor[0]:
        print("Inside copy", job , buckets)

        src_bucket = buckets[0]
        dest_bucket = buckets[1]
        src_path = job[0] 
        dest_path = job[1]
        src_loc = {"Bucket": src_bucket, "Key": src_path}
        #loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        #session = aiobotocore.get_session()
        async with aioboto3.client('s3') as asyncs3:
            print("s3 copy from {} to {}".format(src_path, dest_path))
            resp = await asyncs3.copy_object(Bucket=dest_bucket, Key=dest_path, CopySource=src_loc)
            print("done ----->", resp)
        print("file copy done")
```

Basically I want to copy multiple files in one shot, searching for quickest way to copy data from one s3 bucket to another.